# How to keep neighbors from connecting to my laptop bluetooth?

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, security

ubuntu 22.04 here on a lenovo thinkpad carbon x 7th generation. I currently have bluetooth enabled via the bluez and blueman packages.

I keep getting notifications that different devices are connecting to my bluetooth. When i go to the bluetooth section of settings, i can see that my bluetooth is visible. I have tried making it hidden via blueman > preferences, but that doesn't seem to stick. When i close down the app and re-open it, i can see that i'm back to "always visible"

Worse, i live in an apt and my neighbors have a ton of bluetooth devices that keep connecting to my laptop (despite me never having attempted to pair them). I've gone through blueman and removed them, but they just reappear a few seconds later. They still have the same id (78:6D:EB:E0:AA:2E is the biggest offender). I've tried bluetoothctl to block and remove (`block 78:6D:EB:E0:AA:2E` and `remove 78:6D:EB:E0:AA:2E`) but that doesn't seem to stick either. How do I keep them from constantly reconnecting (other than simply turning bluetooth off)?

If there's any log or config files I should be sharing, please let me know.

Comment: https://aruljohn.com/mac/786DEBE0AA2E says it's a GE Lighting device, probably a smart light bulb. Are you sure it is trying to connect to your device? When you open the menu to discover, it might show nearby devices not just paired devices

Comment: Thanks for looking that up. I think it's connecting because it says "Connected" and then it disappears from the list. Using bluetoothctl also logs it as connecting for half a second.  Granted, I could be misunderstanding because I don't really know much about bluetooth. I've been using a wired thinkpad keyboard and just using the little red mouse in there instead because I'm sick of all the popups and possible security issues.

Comment: It shouldn't be able to remember you so try entering `discoverable off` in bluetoothctl